# Magento 2 How to Remove a Top Link Using Layout ifconfig

Tags: magento2, layout, magento-2.1, ifconfig

In Magento 2 how can I remove a link from `top.links` via layout? I am assuming you can do this because every link is block in the top.links node is a its own block.

> This is was a question I had earlier today. Because there is little
>   information on this I will answer my own question and hopefully this
>   will be of help for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say if you want to remove the sign in link. You first need to find out the parent block, then create a conditional action (using the ifconfig attribute) to unset a child block and then pass the alias/name of the child block as an argument.

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="section_id/group/enabled">
        <argument name="alias" xsi:type="string">authorization-link</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Note: ifconfig only accepts true or false (1/0) and will only unset the child if the value is true.